# "Slide to snooze" on lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios

I have seen several alarm clock apps, such as Rise, display a "slide to snooze" message in the iPhone lock screen, where it normally says "slide to unlock". The app is in the foreground, but the screen is locked. How is this being done? I couldn't find any mention of it on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [UILocalNotification documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you will see a property of `UILocalNotification` named `alertAction`. This property is described as follows:

> The alert action is the title of the right button of the alert or the value of the unlock slider, where the value replaces “unlock” in “slide to unlock”.

So, if you want a custom "slide to unlock" text, `alertAction` is the property to change.